# Saxon Migration DynamicQueryContext Issue

Tags: java, saxon

Recently I was upgrading some JARs in my application. SO I updated the Saxon JAR to 9.9 version. Now I see the:

```
DynamicQueryContext.setContextItem()
```

has gone through some change.

Now the API documentation says to look into,

```
Configuration.buildDocumentTree(javax.xml.transform.Source)
```

But this doesn't even return an Item object!

So is this the right way to go about it?

```
dynamicQueryContext.setContextItem((getConfiguration().buildDocumentTree(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))).getRootNode());
```

This is an old dormant code, and I am not Saxon expert to be honest. Just reading the API documentation and trying to figure this puzzle out. At least, Eclipse shows no errors this way.

Comment: The preferred API to use XQuery (?) in Saxon 9.9 is documented at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/api-query/s9api-query.html.

Answer (score 1):

The API involving StaticQueryContext and DynamicQueryContext was an unfortunate mixture of methods intended for internal use and methods intended for application use, and it had become very difficult to maintain compatibility across releases, so it was replaced over 10 years ago with the s9api API which has proved a much better design and much more stable.

You haven't said which version you are migrating from, so it's difficult for me to see exactly when it changed and why; but I don't see any change in setContextItem() between 9.1 and 9.9.

`Configuration.buildDocumentTree(javax.xml.transform.Source)` is a relatively recent introduction (9.8?). In the past, methods like this returned a `DocumentInfo` representing a document node (which is an Item), but this caused problem for functions that return a tree rooted at an element node, because there was no-where to put the information that related to the tree as a whole rather than its root node. So we introduced the `TreeInfo` class to represent the tree, and you can get the `NodeInfo` item at the root of the tree using `TreeInfo.getRootNode()`.

If you can, move to s9api interfaces and you will find a much higher level of API stability in future.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The application is currently using Saxon 9.0 and I am trying to get it to work with 9.9. The objective was to get it to work with minimal work as possible. I also see that the `setParameter(StructuredQName expandedName, GroundedValue<?> value)` in DynamicQueryContext has changed a lot in this time. I will have to look into that as well. I will go over s9api and if its a simple enough change, I will go for it. Thanks for the clarification though. It helped!